# Update HTML of element on click toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to update the HTML of a  field in a table when it's clicked. When it's clicked, a class is applied and alternates between 'headerSortUp' and 'headerSortDown'.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('click', "table#archive-table thead tr th.headerSortUp", function(){ 
    $(this).html('Date <span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">up</span>');
});
```

I also need to add so if the class is 'headerSortDpwn' is updates the HTML to `Date <span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">down</span>`

Let me know if you can help or if I haven't made myself clear.

Thanks,
R

UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/Rx9pD/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#archive-table ').on('click', "th", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('headerSortUp')) $(this).html('Date <span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">up</span>');
    else if ($(this).hasClass('headerSortDown')) $(this).html('Date <span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">down</span>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel like this should work, but it's not updating the HTML...

Comment: @rdck: Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ I can then look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table#archive-table thead tr th").click(function (e) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("headerSortUp")){
        $(this).removeClass("headerSortUp");
        $(this).addClass("headerSortDown");
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("headerSortDown");
        $(this).addClass("headerSortUp");
        S(this).html('Date <span class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">down</span>');
    }
});
```

in the html() function put the entire the entire html instead of what you provided in your question. I am also assuming the `headerSortUp` class is initially applied to your `th` cell.